# webpack to allow import of all sass files? i.e @import 'components/**/*'

Tags: sass, webpack

I'm currently using css-loader, node-sass, sass-loader and style-loader packages within webpack to compile my sass files, here is how my loader looks at the moment:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: 'style!css!sass'
}
```

I want to use folder structure like this for my styles

```
styles
  components/
  main.sass
```

and somehow within main.sass I want to import everything from components folder so something like `@import './components/**/*'` is this possible via webpack?

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix a Sass import with '~' to tell the [Sass loade](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader#imports)r to use webpack's `require()` resolution on the import. Once webpack is in charge of the import you have some flexibility.

If you do a dynamic require, e.g. `require('~./components/' + someVar + '.scss')`, webpack can't evaluate the variable at build time and it bundles all the possible files in that directory, and the actual resolution of the `require()` happens at runtime (which can lead to errors at runtime if you've asked for something that doesn't exist). Not sure off the top of my head if that would give you what you need (all the files bundled) or if you would still need to explicitly `require()` each partial -- but if that's the case you could easily loop through all the files in the directory and require each one.

More on how you can [leverage webpack's dynamic requires and loading context.](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html)